# Can RecyclerView be a parent of CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm new to Android development so I intend to use REST API to fetch blog content. I'll be using RecyclerView for sake of memory and I don't intend to use lists, but rather CardView. Because I want the CardView to inherit all the goodies of RecyclerView.

So in the layout, CardView will the child of RecyclerView instead of ListView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
      ...>

      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...>
    ...
    ...
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, `RecyclerView` is a substitute for a `ListView` so yes, you can have a `RecyclerView` with multiple `CardViews` in it.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can have `CardView`s as items of `RecyclerView`. But this is not how the XML layout should look like.

Define your list item XML layout in a separate file where `CardView` will be the root tag. Use recycler view adapter to create items and put them into your recycler view.

Comment: I found something similar online but don't know if I should implement it http://techlovejump.com/android-cardview-widget-example-add-to-list-using-recyclerview/

Comment: Example #2 looks like what you need.